# Is it possible to convert an aws codepipeline to bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-codepipeline, blue-green-deployment

I would like to deploy my application to [aws blue-green environment](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/01/aws-codedeploy-introduces-blue-green-deployments/). 
I can find aws codepipeline to integrate the blue-green environment. But I can't find anything for bitbucket.

Comment: Is your question "How to convert CodePipeline to Bitbucket Pipeline?" or "How to implement blue-green deployment with Bitbucket Pipeline"?

Comment: The latter one @nickolay.laptev How to implement blue-green deployment with Bitbucket Pipeline

Answer (score 1):

> How to implement blue-green deployment with Bitbucket Pipeline?

Practically it's not possible and makes no sense.
Bitbucket Pipeline is CI tool, not CD tool.
 We can still perform deployment there but it's similar to shell script execution.
Also even as CI tool it's very limited in features, because it's quite new in the market.

Corner case for us here will be performing rollback basing on some conditions. It's not possible in Bitbucket Pipeline.

We can make this rollback manually or semi-automatic by executing sequential tasks in Bitbucket Pipeline, but it will be similar to shell script execution. We can do this in command line without Bitbucket.

Please note that blue-green deployment assumes coexistence of different versions of your product at the same time. It raises many questions to your product and it's deployment. It doesn't relate to CI/CD tool you use.